# I am getting a wrong output for the Valid Palindrome Problem

Tags: python, regex, for-loop, reverse, palindrome

I am a beginner. I am learning Python and trying to do the `Leetcode` problems. I am getting false for the second test case, but for the first case, I am getting false instead of true. Pardon my lack of knowledge. I am willing to learn so please let me know where am I making the mistake.
Ques: Given a string s, determine if it is a palindrome, considering only alphanumeric characters and ignoring cases.

```
s= "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama"
```

My Output: false
Expected Output: true

My solution:

```
class Solution:

    def isPalindrome(self, s: str) -> bool:
        for i in range(0,len(s)-1):
            if s==s[::-1]:
                import re
                regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')
                s=regex.sub('', 'ab3d*E')
                s_lower = s.lower()
                return s_lower
            else:
                break
```

Comment: ```s==s[::-1]``` is checked before extracting the letters

Answer (score 1):

Why not try using `re.sub` this way:

```
>>> s = "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama"
>>> x = re.sub('[^a-z]', '', s.lower())
>>> x[::-1] == x
True
>>>
```

Comment: Alphanumeric includes numbers. And could be shorter if you `lower` first.

Comment: Just checked, LeetCode's test suite actually contains the test case `"0P"` and expects `False`.

Comment: Btw your question is odd. They *are* trying `re.sub` (well, via `compile`, but still).

Comment: Ah darn, I hadn't looked closely, could've pointed out that you even suggested the exact same pattern :-)

Answer (score 1):

try this code, I got accept
*(I use String `isalnum()` Method)*:

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, s: str) -> bool:
        string=""
        ss=s.lower()
        
        string = ''.join(x for x in ss if x.isalnum())    
        
        bol= string == string[::-1]
                
        return bol
```

output:

```
# "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama"
True
# "race a car"
False
```

Comment: Oh right, `isalnum` exists. Short Python 2 version: `s = filter(unicode.isalnum, s.lower())` `return s == s[::-1]`.